# For object property detection, should I use 'in' or 'hasOwnProperty'?

Tags: javascript

I just read an [article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1453/7-javascript-basics-many-developers-aren-t-using-properly) that suggests using the `in` operator for browser feature and object property detection.  The example given is to use:

```
if("geolocation" in navigator) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

rather than:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

However, it made no mention of hasOwnProperty, despite the fact that the following code seems to work just fine:

```
if(navigator.hasOwnProperty('geolocation')) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Are there situations where I should use `in` instead of `hasOwnProperty` or vice-versa? Or is it simply a stylistic choice?

Comment: FWIW, `typeof object.property !== undefined` is a lot faster than `in` or `hasOwnProperty`: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/2 (granted, it's not exactly equivalent, but that won't make a difference in most cases). Of course performance is only a concern if you have to do a lot of property checking (and feature detection is *not* one of those cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference, from the MDN on [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> Every object descended from Object inherits the `hasOwnProperty` method.
>   This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a **direct property** of that object; unlike the `in`
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

My advice is, if you created the object then you can use `in` or a simple lookup most of the time, but consider your options when there's a prototype chain in place. If it's a native object or some other object you have no control of, then use `hasOwnProperty`.